# How do I solve this for $N$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find $N$ when
>   $N$ mod $13=5$, $N$ mod $19$=$1$ and $N$ mod $53$=$41$.

*I am not specifically concerned with this example.* I would like to be shown a solution in general. I would like to see:

- What conditions are needed for $N$ to exist.
- Whether $N$ would be finite or infinite.
- How one would solve for $N$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Chinese Remainder Theorem.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Have a look at the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

Using chinese number theorem is probably the strongest option you have got.

BUT often when there are multiple constraints on $N$ you can use often get away with common sense, specially when a range is provided for $N$